# Is there a way to style RSS/ATOM feeds?

Tags: css, rss, atom-feed

One thing I've noticed is that my blog posts show up very different in my RSS feed than on my actual blog. Presumably, this is because CSS doesn't apply to RSS feeds, so layout is messed up.

For example, if in my feed I have something like this:

```
<div class="right-floater">Some right-float text!</div>
<p>Normal paragraph text.</p>
```

...on the blog, it will display properly. In the actual RSS feed, it will be laid out sans CSS and the `<div>` will be to the left of the `<p>`, presumably.

Is there a way to add in a link to CSS stylesheet information to have reader applications load the styles so that things style properly when viewed in an application like Google Reader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the feed reader, but yes, most will ignore CSS entirely. Some (like [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader/)) will pay attention to the `style` attribute if it's "simple" enough, so you could write:

```
<div style="float: right">Some right-float text!</div>
<p>Normal paragraph text.</p>
```

For security reasons (primarily XSS avoidance), CSS has to pass through a filter. Only "known safe" CSS is allowed through.

Comment: Since I'm using WordPress, lots of styles are simply added by classes provided by `styles.css`. When I'm writing posts, would it just be better to style things without using classes so that this will work, or is there a way to include an external CSS file with a feed?

Comment: @TK It depends on the feed reader, but at least for Google Reader, there isn't any way to use external CSS. In fact, I believe the `class` attribute is completely filtered out. We'd actually talked about trying to make it possible to include a stylesheet in the feed (I used to work on Google Reader, and was the main person behind its HTML scrubber) but doing this correctly is very tricky, and wasn't considered high enough priority to justify the effort.

Comment: So the solution would be to simply embed important layout in `style` attributes, rather than in CSS classes? I can do that, I suppose. I'll  just make that my default when writing posts from now on, as I'm composing them in HTML anyway.

Comment: @TK Yes, though if you use appropriate structural markup the need for `style` should be pretty minimal. The one place where people often need to use `style` is floating images.

Comment: Exactly. Thanks a bunch, this answers my question.